# How do I exclude files from a jest cli command?

Tags: regex, bash, jestjs

Is there a jest equivalent, or a way of doing it in bash, to the git regex approach for including files that match one regex (all files in the `/tests` folder), but then exclude any that match a second (any test files that include `API` in the name)? e.g.

```
git ls-files -- 'tests' ':!:*API*'
```

I would like to do it as single line command because I want to be able to run all the tests in the `/tests` directory, but in two mutually exclusive sets using a single `yarn test` script from my `package.json` file.

---

EDIT: Expanding on Brenda J. Butler's answer:

```
yarn jest `find tests -type f ! -name \*API\* | grep -v .DS_`
```

1. Realising that `jest` can take either a regex OR a file list,
2. using backticks to do a bash substitution, and
3. additionally, as this is on MacOS, using a `grep -v` to also pull out the `.DS_Store` from the file list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash:

```
# finding files under tests whose names don't contain API
$ find tests -type f ! -name \*API\*

# finding files under tests whose names contain API
$ find tests -type f -name \*API\*
```

Comment: Thanks Brenda. However, I want to run that as part of a `jest regex ---options` command, without having to write a bash script.

Comment: Ok.  Well the original question said "or bash" ... so I answered bash.  Maybe a jest-knowledgeable person will come along.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sniping! Just that I wanted it in a single command so that I didn't have to add a bash script to the repo ( which would then require tests - no really :-( - from the client )

Comment: No need for apology!  And thanks for the upvote : -)  Good luck getting the jest version of the answer.  Unfortunately I don't know jest at all.

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track. Had a "D'oh!" moment...